# How to add custom filed in the body of exception using Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I want to throw exception which will contain a custom field like user's phone number.

```
 foundUser.ifPresent(fu -> {
   throw new UserNotVerified("Check your email inbox to verify your account or " +
                "resend code to phone number", fu.getPhoneNumber());
 });
```

**UserNotVerified.class**

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UserNotVerified extends RuntimeException{
    private final String phoneNumber;

    public UserNotVerified(String message, String phoneNumber) {
        super(message);
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Then I created **ControllerAdvice** class that will give back custom response:

```
@ExceptionHandler(UserNotVerified.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(UserNotVerified exception) {
        UserNotVerifiedResponse apiException =
                new UserNotVerifiedResponse(exception.getPhoneNumber());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```

Custom response should look like this:

```
public class UserNotVerifiedResponse {
    private final String phoneNumber;

    public UserNotVerifiedResponse(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

But when I run the code my exception still looks like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-17T13:10:36.836+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/auth-api/login"
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the `handleException(UserNotVerified exception)` is being reached? I'm assuming you also have `@ControllerAdvice` or `@RestControllerAdvice` on your ControllerAdvice class?

Comment: @HermannSteidel yes I do

Comment: I'll have to play around but what I find curious is that when you return `return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);` I would expect the response JSON to represent the `UserNotVerified` NOT the default spring response message like you are seeing. This is what makes me think Spring is ignoring your controller advice.